# MYSQL google interview query

Tags: mysql, sql

I was asked this question on the interview, and I could not do it completely

You have a table where you have date, user_id, song_id and count. It shows at the end of each day how many times in  history a user has listened to a given song. So count is cumulative sum.

question:  You have to update this on a daily basis **based** on a second table that records in real time when a user listens to a given song. Basically, at the end of each day, you go to this second table and pull a count of each user/song combination and then add this count to the first table that has the lifetime count. If it is the first time a user has listened to a given song, you won't have this pair in the lifetime table, so you have to create the pair there and then add the count of the last day.

My answer: Using a full outer join between life time count and last day count and then sum the two...could not update the table though.

Any help?

Comment: I don't find this question opinion-based at all.

Answer (score 1):

You would do this using MySQL's equivalent of "upsert":  `on duplicate key update`.  Something like this:

```
insert into history(date, user_id, song_id, count)
    select date(rt.datetime), rt.user_id, rt.song_id, count(*)
    from realtime rt
    where rt.datetime >= curdate() - interval 1 day and
          rt.datetime < curdate()
    group by rt.user_id, rt.song_id
    on duplicate key update count = count + values(count);
```

I should answer that your answer is all the more wrong because MySQL does not support `full outer join`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, Can you help in writing this query in SQL as well?

Comment: @USER8129 surely the moment's passed